# How do I put a tag in my "About me" block?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

I'd like to put a [tag] link in my "About Me" section. How can I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
[tag:tagname]
```

Result:

[tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagname)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the normal syntax:

```
[tag:markdown]
```

This will render (and link) correctly as:

[markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown)